# Visual guide of AppKit controls?

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, controls, appkit

Is there a visual guide to the controls in Mac OS/X AppKit?

Take, for instance, the following control that appears at different places in XCode UI:

[image: Unknown control]

I don't know which AppKit control is that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a series of `NSRadioButton` views in an `NSMatrix`. You can determine the former using Accessibility Inspector, which will tell you that these buttons are of the accessibility class `AXRadioButton`. You can determine the latter using [f-script](http://fscript.org). (You'll need the new [10.7 injection workflow](http://keli.hu/blog/f-script-injection-service-for-lion/) that isn't in 2.1 yet.)

Comment: This is an excellent answer: I don't need a visual guide any more! Thanks!