# Custom Cocoa Control, what exactly is this?

Tags: macos, cocoa, controls, nscontrol

There are several applications that use this control. One I think most everyone knows is Xcode, another is AppStar. I am interested to know what control this is and where I can find an open source implementation of it:

**"The box thingy within the bounds of the red area where it says Build Succeeded"**

[image]

One developer said he has seen this called a **"Jukebox View"**, but I cannot find anything anywhere with that name, or anything like it.

**Does anyone know what exactly this control is called or if there is in fact an open source implementation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Visual guide of AppKit controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419660/visual-guide-of-appkit-controls) for an explanation of how to explore this question. This is called `IDEActivityView`. It is not a public class.

Comment: Good thing the project I am working on won't be public! Where exactly can I get this `IDEActivityView ` control from to use it in my application? Google search of "IDEActivityView" turns up nothing useful.

Comment: It's part of Xcode. "it is not a public class." If you want to spelunk inside of IDEKit, it's in there. But nothing about IDEKit is designed to be pulled out and used in your own projects. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework

Comment: Okay, I understand that and see it in the Xcode class dump. However, there is another application "AppStar" that uses a similar control. Screenshot: http://snapplr.com/gy4a

Comment: Sure. They probably built their own. Note how it doesn't look that much like Xcode's? The one you posted is `IDEActivityView`. If you use the link I provided, you'll learn the tools I used to discover that fact, and you can use the same technique to explore AppStar.